# how can i hide parameters sending to action class from left navigation

Tags: java, struts2

I am using struts 2 in my project, and I want to send some parameters after clicking a leftnav link or an icon to my action class. Here in this scenario, the parameters is visible in the URL,so I wants to hide it. Below is my left nav link code:

```
<s:a   href="getFormFields.do?regionId=%{regionId}&nbdcId=%{nbdcId}&regionName=%{regionName}&accountName=%{accountName}&formPage=edit"  ></s:a>.
```

Comment: You will have to use form variables, and submit the form as POST on click of the nav link.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, they're in the URL.

You could POST a form, although the parameters are still visible in the request body.